# Start generating auto increment column value from default in slick

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

I having a table column holds auto increment value. I want to start incrementing from specified vlaue.
 How can i specify this functionality in slick ddl.

Code i am using for column of table creation in slick is :

```
def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O.NotNull)
```

I have come across [this](http://blog.lunatech.com/2013/08/21/slick-column-definitions) article but didn't find exact solution.

```
create table "COCKTAIL" (
  "ID" BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 100000) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "NAME" VARCHAR NOT NULL)
```

Can someone help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `O.Default(...)`? Look at here: [ColumnOption](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/0.11.1/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.ColumnOption%24).

```
def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O.NotNull,O.Default(100000))
```

Comment: I tried that option. It is throwing exception of multiple initialization :  ERROR: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table

Comment: Try to remove "O.PrimaryKey"(maybe it set the default value)  or use  "Default(100000)".

Comment: seems Default will give a default value. I don't want it to be default value. I want to increment from that default value. Only first row value should start from there

Comment: Then you should set the value of the first record's id.

Comment: After inserting i updated record id to 10000 and then inserted second one.It is still counting from 0. in this case, new inserted record id is one... that is also not working