# Slick and Play Evolution: Creating a SERIAL or Sequence after changing default start value

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, slick-2.0

I have a table which uses O.AutoInc as ID generator, which is a primary key.

Sample Code:

```
case class User(id:Long)
class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag,"USERS"){
   def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
   def * = (id) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

This creates a table with SERIAL field and a sequence with start value 1. Is there a way to change this start value?

Another option is to create sequence like:

```
Sequence[Long]("USERS_ID_seq") start 200000 inc 1
```

and use it something like:

```
def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.DBType("nextval('USERS_ID_seq')"))
```

I am not sure whether it will work as I cant find a way to make play use this sequence.

So is there a way to tell play evolution to use this sequence?

Comment: You can use O.default, like this: `def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O.NotNull,O.Default(100000))`. For more info: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756514/start-generating-auto-increment-column-value-from-default-in-slick)

Comment: @user3003216, it wont work. That answer is wrong. O.AutoInc creates a SERIAL field and it has a default for the SEQUENCE it automatically generated. Now if I add O.Default, it will create two defaults.

Comment: Why would you use 2 Sequences at a time ? Choose one, either use your current code or add O.Default.

Comment: The specified part is in the last of this link. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html